# Java Regular Expression remove Matches from String

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the found matches from my String. So my Code sample currently looks like this:

```
public void checkText() {
    String helper = "985, 913, 123, SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{3}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(helper);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String newtext = "Number: " + matcher.group() + "\n"+ newtext;
        helper.replaceAll(matcher.group(),"");
    }
    newtext = newtext + "________________\n"+ helper;
    editText.setText(newtext);
}
```

So my input string is: `985, 913, 123, SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText`

After running the code what I would like to see is this:

```
Number: 985
Number: 913
Number: 123
________________________
SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText
```

Anyone can tell me whats wrong in my current code?

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: You're replacing only numbers and expect commas to be replaced as well. You should add them to your regex as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you could update in the code:

- You should set the return of the replacement to `helper`
- If you only replace with an empty string, your string will start with `, , ,` in the replacement leaving the comma's and the follwing space
- You might initialize the variable `String newtext = "";`

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rWdwlD)

Your code might look like:

```
String helper = "985, 913, 123, SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{3}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(helper);
String newtext = "";

while (matcher.find()) {
    newtext = "Number: " + matcher.group() + "\n"+ newtext;
    helper = helper.replaceAll(matcher.group() + ", ","");
}
newtext = newtext + "________________\n"+ helper;
System.out.println(newtext);
```

Result:

```
Number: 123
Number: 913
Number: 985
________________
SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using the `Matcher` class you can also use the method `Matcher.appendReplacement` for the replacement:

```
public void checkText() {
    String helper = "985, 913, 123, SomeotherText, MoreText, MoreText";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d{3}, ");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(helper);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Number:"+matcher.group());
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```